# What happens to objects created in a method which is called repeatedly?

Tags: java, object, methods

Here goes the question:

If I am creating a single object by calling a method (accepting say a single parameter) but I am calling the method multiple times passing a new argument each time.

```
void create(String name) {

        // Create a dog
        Dog dog = new Dog(name);
}
```

On the above code, if I call the method multiple times passing a unique dog name each time, the dog variable, at last, is only going to point to the Dog object with the name that the method received at last.

My question is what happens to the previous dog objects? Are they still in heap memory but there's nothing to retrieve it?

Thank you for taking the time to read this. Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Anytime you execute `new` keyword, JVM allocates a new memory chunk, on the Heap, for storing the instance.

> *If I am creating a single object by calling a method (accepting say a single parameter) but I am calling the method multiple times passing a new argument each time. My question is what happens to the previous dog objects? Are they still in heap memory but there's nothing to retrieve it?*

Each time you will call your method, a new stack frame will be allocated on the Stack Memory of the current thread, and your object reference will be declared within the scope of that frame, which means, that it will be ineligible for Garbage Collection (GC) *as long as* your method frame is alive. It will, however, become eligible for GC after your method returns/exits.

The only exception, where the object created in the method is not GCed, is if you pass its references somewhere else. In this case, object still has something referring to it, and therefore, it will be maintained by the heap, and it will not be GCed.

<sup>*Note, that you don't control when GC runs, object may be destroyed immediately after method returns, or after some [usually - little] while; however, in either case, you are losing the reference to it after method returns, which means, that it will eventually be GCed.*</sup>

Comment: This answer does give the correct high level information regarding the GC.
It is possible at times for applications to allocate memory at a rate greater than the GC is able to clear it but that would not apply in this scenario. The answer could potentially touch upon that.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari could you elaborate on the scenario you have in mind?

Comment: Scenarios such as game development where instantiating a common object can be quite expensive. I don't know if that's a place Java developers work with often ( I myself am using something else ). It's more a general managed memory point to keep in mind.

Comment: For the intermediate (or machine) level code, it does not matter you develop a game, ERP system or console application. Nor does it matter for high level ptogramming languages. I initially thought you were referring to GC process. At a very high level, Java manages memory as I wrote above. If the allocated object is X bytes, complete disposal of it will set X bytes free. There are different layers of GC, but that's not important here.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what happens to the previous dog objects? Are they still in heap memory but there's nothing to retrieve it?

They may stay around for a little time, until the Garbage Collector kicks in or the JVM exits.

```
void create(String name) {

    // Create a dog
    //dog is available in the method
    Dog dog = new Dog(name);
    
    return;
    //dog is not reachable==> The GC can collect it.
}
```